# Non-local cosmology

Tags: cosmology, terminology, non-locality

Does anyone know what exactly [non-local cosmology](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=non+local+cosmology) mean? Does it have anything to do with the scale we are dealing with or is it just the idea of objects interacting with each other despite having very large distances (like in Quantum entanglement)? And what are the assumption on the Hamiltonian (or Lagrangian) that would make it a Non-Local Cosmological problem?

Comment: Cosmology with non-local forces? It's not clear why we even need that. Cosmology is not plagued by theoretical concerns about the locality of force laws right now but by our missing observational knowledge of what actually happened.